# Easy deploying process in overlays

Tags: java, maven, web, build, overlay

I have two web applications Web-main and Web-sub, and a simple java project Maven-app.

Web-sub is having dependency of Maven-app.While, Web-main is having dependency of Web-sub.

Building Maven-app results in a jar file.Then, I build Web-sub which includes Maven-app's jar file and packaged into a war file.Finally, building Web-main results in a war file which contains war file of Web-sub.

Now, if I do any changes in my java project, I need to do all these installations again so that target war of my main Web-application(i.e. Web-main) contains the updated jar.

This becomes very tedious process when I have very minor changes(e.g. typo mistakes).

One solution could be to script on shell which will make this jar directly copied to war of Web-main, but I am not able to do it.
How to do it ? Or 
Can I do it in other way which will speed up my build process?

Comment: Using a continuous integration server like jenkins,or similar you can some how take out the process of manually building stuff. With this if u change sumthing in the Maven-app,then just build the changed project and run the parent-build,in this case the Web-main app,so all the required dependency are pulled in. If Web-suff is an independant project on its own,then build the project from there. I am also curious to see what other might have to say for this

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable reply.I actually want to do it without any changes in configuration of project.

Comment: having a script that will do all this stuff can also work, but I am not able to script for this automation